# After I updated to Xcode7, my apps can't connect to specific address

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, network-programming, ios9, nsurl

In some of my apps I use `NSURL` to connect to a specific address; it doesn't work following my upgrade to Xcode 7.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From iOS 9 onwards, you have to set the **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** key to **YES** under **NSAppTransportSecurity** dictionary in your .plist file. Hope this helps!

[image: Plist configuration]